# updating dataframe with iterrows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, updates, series

I want to compute values in a dataframe doing it by rows with iterrows, as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ list( range( 0, 6)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(10,16)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(20,26)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(30,36)) + [np.NaN] * 5])

for (index, row) in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[ index, 6: 11] =  row[ 1: 6] - row [ 0]
```

Why df is not updated ?

I even tried to replace `row[ 1: 6] - row [ 0]` with `df.loc[ index, 1: 6] - df.loc[ index, 0]` and it doesn't work. Is it a trivial mistake or more subtile concept I don't master ? And also is there something more performant ?

Comment: you should up vote and accept (click the checkmark) the answer that solved your problem. This lets future visitors clearly know what worked for you and what might work for them. Do not add another response that just summarizes things.

Comment: @Paul H: I did upvote both of the answers. I had a message saying my vote is recorded. Although, since I haven't enough reputation (<15) they don"t show up!

Answer (score 3):

Pandas assignment with `loc` does index alignment before assignment. Your columns names will be misaligned here. Do this:

```
for (index, row) in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[ index, 6: 11] =  (row[ 1: 6] - row [ 0]).values

df
Out[23]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5    6    7    8    9    10
0   0   1   2   3   4   5  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
2  20  21  22  23  24  25  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
3  30  31  32  33  34  35  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics) for more information:

> Warning pandas aligns all AXES when setting Series and DataFrame from
>   .loc, .iloc and .ix. This will not modify df because the column
>   alignment is before value assignment.

Comment: This answer and the documentation make no sense to me. What does "aligning" mean? Why does .loc align things, but [] doesn't?

Comment: loc aligns things because when you do assignment between similar indexed df and series, the vast majority of the time this is what you expect. The culprit in OP is more that no domain specific index was ever defined, and that the index access is performed as a sort of blind windowing filter against the df: this is a particular case. With two appropriate indexed I would then assign directly my filtered data and the magic of alignment would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You rarely ever need to iterate through a dataframe. I would just do this:

```
import pandas
import numpy
x = numpy.array([
    list(range(0, 6)) + [numpy.NaN] * 5, 
    list(range(10, 16)) + [numpy.NaN] * 5, 
    list(range(20, 26)) + [numpy.NaN] * 5, 
    list(range(30, 36)) + [numpy.NaN] * 5
])

x[:, 6:] = x[:, 1:6] - x[:, [0]]

pandas.DataFrame(x)
```

Gives me:

```
     0     1     2     3     4     5    6    7    8    9    10
0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
2  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
3  30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  35.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx. I added up the two solutions :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ list( range( 0, 6)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(10,16)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(20,26)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(30,36)) + [np.NaN] * 5])

df.loc[ :, 6: 11] =  (row[ 1: 6] - row [ 0]).values
df

Out[10]:
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
1   10  11  12  13  14  15  1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
2   20  21  22  23  24  25  1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
3   30  31  32  33  34  35  1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
```

EDIT:

As a matter of fact this is not working! In my real example there is a problem and data is not what it should be looking at this small example.

The iterrows() solution is slow (my data frame is around 9000*500) so I'm going to numpy array solution. Converting the data frame to numpy array, doing the calculation and going back to data frame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([ list( range( 0, 6)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(10,16)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(20,26)) + [np.NaN] * 5, 
                    list( range(30,36)) + [np.NaN] * 5])
x = df.as_matrix()
x[ :, 6:] = x[ :, 1: 6] - x[ :, [ 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame( x, columns=df.columns, index=df.index, dtype='int8')
df

Out[15]:
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   1   2   3   4   5
1   10  11  12  13  14  15  1   2   3   4   5
2   20  21  22  23  24  25  1   2   3   4   5
3   30  31  32  33  34  35  1   2   3   4   5
In [ ]:
```